# How do I get the CT object of the XWPFSDT so I can change the runs in it?

Tags: apache-poi

In the Apache Poi, how do I get the CT object of the XWPFSDT so I can change the runs in it?

In other Apache Poi elements it's possible to get the CT elements, but not in the XWPFSDT.

Comment: Generally one should try to avoid using the low-level `CT` classes, and instead use the higher-level `XWPF` wrappers. Why do you think you need to get at the low level ones?

Comment: SDT support is only minimal. The only way to get at it is to start from the CT class of the container. But doing this could get you into a situation where you are forced to refactor later in order to upgrade POI since the API is subject to change.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Yes, that's what I did and it work. The only way is to go to the container, obtain the CT objects, and change things in the CT-level.